# Why does adding a field to be required in mongoose cause a validation error?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

In my schema I have

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
```

However, when I try testing this out with Postman, creating a fake user:

```
{
  "email": "amh@gmail.com",
  "password": "1232",
  "firstName": "alanh"
}
```

mongoose then throws this:

```
ValidationError: user validation failed
    at MongooseError.ValidationError (/Users/alanh/test2/auth/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:22:11)
    at model.Document.invalidate (/Users/alanh/test2/auth/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1410:32)
    at /Users/alanh/test2/auth/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1286:17
    at validate (/Users/alanh/test2/auth/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:705:7)
    at /Users/alanh/test2/auth/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:742:9
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (/Users/alanh/test2/auth/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:710:19)
    at /Users/alanh/test2/auth/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1284:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

But if I change the requirement of `firstName` to `false`, then it works fine. What is causing this error and how do I get it to work so that I can have `firstName` be required?

Comment: `)};` should be `});` at the end of the `schema` .is that a typo?

Comment: @ravishankar yeah, i hand typed it into the text area, but that's not the issue. Let me fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you simplify it down to a [MCVE]?

Comment: i hope, rest others are correctly typed, otherwise they may hide the original code which is causing the issue.

Comment: @ravi No, I typed in to the stack overflow text area the schema. There aren't typos with the code, I have a linter on.